# How do I split out parameters from a url in Iron Router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a Meteor web app. and I have URL's formatted like this:

`/box/bx_0/12345/bx_1/67890/` ...etc...

I want to be able to extract the pairs like this into an array in my Router file:

```
boxes['bx_0'] = 12345;
boxes['bx_1'] = 67890;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if there is a pack or a convention for this, anyway you could setup a generic route, grab the url, split on "/" and then parse it.

In other words, i think doing it manually should be fast enough to justify not looking for another solution...

Comment: I can't compile now, unfortunately. Have a look on Hooks, check also "this.request" and do your magic. 
https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#hooks